# Node Js formidable Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, formidable

On my local webserver the following code works perfectly, if i send post request with postman.

```
    var postData;

    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req,function(err,fields,files){
        postData = fields;
    });

    var userName = postData.userName;
    var password = postData.password;
```

On Heroku i get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'userName' of undefined

Local is variable postData a form object. On Heroku it us undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of async nature of node.js. Try something like this -

```
var userName, password;

form.parse(req,function(err,fields,files){
        postData = fields;
        userName = postData.userName;
        password = postData.password;
    });
```